# Adding Values stored in a TreeMap

Tags: java, treemap

I'm currently working on an Inventory System where the Key is the Item and the Value is the Number of the Items stored in the Key, I am working with Java 7 and I am fairly new to it as a language. So far this is what I have:

```
    String itemName = item.trim().toLowerCase();  
    if(!add < 1)  
    {  
    if (!invMap.containsKey(itemName)  
    {  
    invMap.put(itemName, add);
    }
```

When the method is run it asks the User for an item(item) and how much of the Item to add (add) I looked in the Javadoc to see if there was a method to retrieve the value stored under the key but I didn't really see anything that helped. I think that if I just get a push in the right direction I should be able to figure the rest out and would prefer hints rather than a direct step by step.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Map.get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) to get the existing value, then add `add` to it, and `put` it back:

```
String itemName = item.trim().toLowerCase();  
if( add >= 1)  
{  
    if ( ! invMap.containsKey( itemName ) )
        invMap.put( itemName, add );
    else
        invMap.put( itemName, add + invMap.get(itemName) );
    }  
}
```

You can shorten this, because `Map.get` and derivatives return `null` if the key is unknown:

```
   Integer old = invMap.get( itemName );
   invMap.put( itemName, old == null ? add : add + old );
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm just curious because before I asked I had tried to do that but on 2 separate lines  with add = invMap.get(itemName) + add; then on the next line invMap.put(itemName, add) and when adding 5 on the first return it would output 10, then on the second it would output 15. so why does this work but not splitting it into 2 lines?

Comment: You're welcome. The Javadoc is your friend ;-) (Also see [TreeMap.get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29).